# Notice: Undefined variable: world in abc.php on line

Tags: php, html

I have a `html/php` code as shown below in the file `abc.php` in which at `Line#A`, I am getting the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: world in abc.php on line#A
```

**html/php code (abc.php) :**

```
if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    $world = $_POST['world'];
}

<form method="post" action="abc.php?id=<?= $id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="world" value="<?= $world; ?>"/> //line#A
</form>
```

This is what I have tried but it doesn't seem to work:

```
if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    $world = isset($_POST['world']);
}
```

Comment: your `$world` is only exists within the scope of the `if` block only. create an empty `$world = ''` before the `if` block should do the trick. though i do curious why i had to comment this given you have 120+ question in php.

Comment: @BagusTesa I have modified my question. My apologies for being not clear before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$world` variable will only be defined if page served via POST method.
So, what you need is define it before the condition:

```php
$world = "";
if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    $world = $_POST['world'];
}

<form method="post" action="abc.php?id=<?= $id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="world" value="<?= $world; ?>"/> //line#A
</form>
```